# bash read quoted element with space from a file and store them into an array

Tags: bash

It's probably a stupid question but I can't find answer, I'm searching for more than an hour now.

I have a file of one line:

```
"Snow In Paradise" "Tomorrow Sea" "Edge Time" "etc ..."
```

I want to be able to do exactly like this example from an other thread:

```
## declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("elem ent1" "e lement2" "element3")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

bash-4.2$ ./test
elem ent1
e lement2
element3
```

Comment: There might be a better answer but the only thing I can think of offhand is to use `grep -o '"[^"]*"' file which will spit out each quoted string on a line by itself (with the quotes intact) you'll need to post-process that for whatever you actually need. [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) will be helpful for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (using `grep`):

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(grep -o '"[^"]*"' file))
...
```